# Need to check to see if UITextField contains two (and only two) Strings of minimum 2 characters each in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield

I am trying to check to see if a user has entered two words in a UITextField.  However, I also need to check that these two words are also a minimum of two characters each.  At the moment, the only way I know how to check the contents of the UITextField is by checking for whitespace between the characters after trimming the whitespace in front of the text.

Here is my code that I am working with:

```
if ([textField.text length] > 0) {

        NSString *name = [textField text];
        NSString *trimmedString = [name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSRange whiteSpaceRange = [trimmedString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        if (whiteSpaceRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Found whitespace");
        }

    }
```

Like I said, my goal is to take the contents of the UITextField, and check to see if the user has entered two words, with each word at least two characters in length. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first try to understand what you are doing:
You are using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` method. From Apple Docs

> Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the receiver
>   characters contained in a given character set.

That implies it returns a single string after removing the character set from both ends. In your case you have provided whiteCharacterSet which is spaces and tabs. This means this method is useful when you want to remove extra spaces from both ends of the string. But your requirement is to separate the two words in the string.

For this purpose NSString have another method that returns the array of separated words.

```
componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
```

> Returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have
>   been divided by characters in a given set.

By using this method you can easily retrieve separated words and using a for loop check whether each word is of minimum two characters or not. Like this:

```
 NSString *str= @"Puneet";
  if ([str length] > 0) {
    NSArray *trimmedArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if(trimmedArray.count > 1)
    {
    for(NSString *str in trimmedArray)
    {
      if(str.length >=2)
        NSLog(@"Have minimum two characters");
      else
        NSLog(@"Dont Have minimum two characters");
    }
    }
    else{
      NSLog(@"No Two words are present");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start would be to use the `NSString` method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to split the text field contents into an `NSArray` of strings.

You could then make sure the array has at least 2 elements (words) and <strike>iterate</strike> use Key Value Coding to make sure each element is at least two characters:

```
NSArray *words = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
if (words.count == 2)
{
    NSNumber *lengthOfShortestWord = [words valueForKeyPath:@"@min.length"];
    if (lengthOfShortestWord.intValue == 2)
    {
        // Success !
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the below check:

```
if ([textField.text length] > 0) {
    NSArray *name = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    if (name.count == 2) {
        if (((NSString *)name[0]).length >= 2) {
            if (((NSString *)name[1]).length >= 2){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the question, that should be at least two characters per word - this is almost correct, it just needs the "== 2" comparisons changed to >= 2 ...